# select from table where column = any value

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I am trying to create a query that will filter a list by 3 columns:

```
age = "2";
gender = "male";
race = "pitbull";

MySqlCommand tempCommand = _DbHandler.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE age = @age AND gender = @gender AND race = @race");
tempCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
tempCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
tempCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", race);

MySqlDataReader tempReader = tempCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

And I want to be able to make lets say the gender column to pick up any value like if this worked:
    gender = "*";

How can I achieve this in one query?

age, gender and race are in parameters in the real code.

Comment: `"*"` is also `string`. If your `gender` will be `"*"`, your query works as you said. I feel I don't understand your question completly..

Comment: With gender = "*" I meant "any value in gender column".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way I can come up with is this, where you only have to change the sql ststement. Now I only hope `dogs` doesn't have a million rows...

```
MySqlCommand tempCommand = _DbHandler.CreateCommand(
          @"SELECT * 
            FROM dogs 
            WHERE (@age='*' OR age = @age)
            AND  (@GENDER='*' OR gender= @gender)
            AND (@race='* OR race = @race");
```

I assume here you provide a * in either parameter to indicate 'no value given' so set

`age="*";`

if you don't want to select dogs based on their age.

Answer (score 1):

To catch any value you simply need to not add that parameter to the query and don't add the condition to the sql.

Something like this should work:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM dogs";

if ( age != "*" || gender != "*" || race != "*" )
  sql += " WHERE 1=1";

if ( age != "*" ) sql += " AND age = @age";
if ( gender != "*" ) sql += " AND gender = @gender";
if ( race != "*" ) sql += " AND race = @race";

MySqlCommand tempCommand = _DbHandler.CreateCommand(sql);

if ( age != "*" ) tempCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
if ( gender != "*" ) tempCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
if ( race != "*" ) tempCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", race);
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the full sql. I'll make some changes in my answer

Comment: Also `age`,`gender` and `race` are `strings`, not `char`.

Comment: Yes, my fault: I'm a bit rusty about C#, and this question could be language agnostic so I mistyped the char/string comparison